# Are the 'blur' and 'focus' events guaranteed to occur in that order?

Tags: javascript

Say you press tab to move focus from element A to B. This should fire the following:

1. [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) on element A
2. [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) on element B

Is it safe to assume they will fire in that order?

Comment: I'm not convinced `focusout` should happen before `blur`... But may I ask why it matters? If your code relies on this event order, you might be doing something in a more difficult way than necessary.

Comment: Edited question to remove `focusout` from the equation. I'm more interested in the order of `blur` and `focus`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`blur`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-blur):

> A user agent MUST dispatch this event when an event target loses focus. The focus MUST be taken from the element before the dispatch of this event type.

[`focus`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#focus):

> A user agent MUST dispatch this event when an event target receives focus. The focus MUST be given to the element before the dispatch of this event type.

Since no two elements can have focus at the same time, it stands to reason that `blur` must occur before `focus`.

Comment: There's more about `focusin` and `focusout` on that page too, if you're still curious about those. It *appears* as though `focusout` should occur before `blur` since it says "*A user agent MUST dispatch this event when an event target is about to lose focus. This event type MUST be dispatched before the element loses focus.*" and `blur` states it occurs when the event target loses focus, but you know browser makers...

Answer (score 0):

Run the below snippet and focus the input on the left, then click into the input on the right and you will see that the order is blur -> focusout -> focus, (in Chrome), but if you check it in Safari, it will be blur -> focusout -> focus. So now, you can not assume that different user agents implement the same event order. Also, focusout and blur are essentially the same thing. The difference is, the blur event does not bubble.

Edit: In response to your edit, yes blur will always occur before focus.

```js
var i1 = document.getElementById("i1");
var i2 = document.getElementById("i2");
var whatHappened = document.getElementById("whatHappened");

i1.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    p.innerText = "focusout";
    whatHappened.appendChild(p); 
});

i1.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    p.innerText = "blur";
    whatHappened.appendChild(p); 
});

i2.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    p.innerText = "focus";
    whatHappened.appendChild(p); 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i1" />
<input type="text" id="i2" />
<div id="whatHappened"></div>
```

Comment: Well, I get `focusout` -> `blur` -> `focus`, so I think that basically proves that no, the order is not consistent.

Comment: Thank you Niet, I added to my answer that the event order is user agent dependent.